# Object creation and destruction order in C++

Tags: c++, temporary-objects, object-construction, object-destruction

I wrote a simple program to learn more about the order of creating and destructing objects in C++ (using Visual Studio 2015). Here it is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    A(string name)
        : name(name)
    {
        cout << "A(" << name << ")::constructor()" << endl;
    }
    ~A()
    {
        cout << "A(" << name << ")::destructor()" << endl;
    }
private:
    string name;
};

class C
{
public:
    C(string name, A a)
        : name(name), a(a)
    {
        cout << "C(" << name << ")::constructor()" << endl;
    }
    ~C()
    {
        cout << "C(" << name << ")::destructor()" << endl;
    }
private:
    string name;
    A a;
};

class B
{
public:
    B(string name)
        : name(name)
    {
        cout << "B(" << name << ")::constructor()" << endl;
    }
    ~B()
    {
        cout << "B(" << name << ")::destructor()" << endl;
    }
private:
    string name;
    A a1{"a1"};
    A a2{"a2"};
    C c1{"c1", a1};
    A a3{"a3"};
};

int main()
{
    B b("b1");
    return 0;
}
```

The output surprised me a little bit (the `a1`s):

```
A(a1)::constructor()
A(a2)::constructor()
C(c1)::constructor()
A(a1)::destructor()
A(a3)::constructor()
B(b1)::constructor()
B(b1)::destructor()
A(a3)::destructor()
C(c1)::destructor()
A(a1)::destructor()
A(a2)::destructor()
A(a1)::destructor()
```

To learn more about what was going on I added information about the instances of objects:

```
    A(string name)
        : name(name)
    {
        cout << "A(" << name << ")::constructor(), this = " << this << endl;
    }
    ~A()
    {
        cout << "A(" << name << ")::destructor(), this = " << this << endl;
    }
```

The result was even more surprising:

```
A(a1)::constructor(), this = 0039FB28
A(a2)::constructor(), this = 0039FB44
C(c1)::constructor()
A(a1)::destructor(), this = 0039F8A8
A(a3)::constructor(), this = 0039FB98
B(b1)::constructor()
B(b1)::destructor()
A(a3)::destructor(), this = 0039FB98
C(c1)::destructor()
A(a1)::destructor(), this = 0039FB7C
A(a2)::destructor(), this = 0039FB44
A(a1)::destructor(), this = 0039FB28
```

Namely, why is `a1`'s constructor only called **once** and destructor **3 times**? I'm passing `a` by value so obviously at least 1 temporary object is created but please explain to me **when** and **how many** `A` instances are created and destroyed?

Comment: You've not annotated many of the other constructors of your class, so you're only seeing a partial picture.

Comment: @KerrekSB Are you referring to printing out of `this` values for classes B and C? Or what?

Comment: The compiler is adding some default constructors that you can't see.

Comment: Notably, the copy constructors

Comment: @Galik: No conforming compiler would do such a nasty thing. Compilers don't generally make stuff up; they follow the rules of the language.

Comment: Please let me know what code to add to see the full picture then.

Comment: @NSP Compiler indeed adds copy constructor. Try to define it yourself as `A(const A& other) {...}` with print statements and you'll see whats going on.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Then what is constructing all the copies?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ [tag:c++] is one of your top tags, are we missing something?

Comment: @MargaretBloom Oops, seems I've been [missing something](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2380766/1413395). Even experts have bad days :-P ... _@Kerrek_ was pointing to _default constructors_, which certainly won't be compiler generated for such case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As already noted in the comments, objects of type `A` are also constructed via copy-construction when you pass them as arguments by value. In order to see this you can add a copy-constructor on your own:

```
A(const A& other)
: name(other.name)
{
    cout << "A(" << name << ")::copy-constructor(), this = " << this << endl;
}
```

Sample output:

```
A(a1)::constructor(), this = 0xbff3512c
A(a2)::constructor(), this = 0xbff35130
A(a1)::copy-constructor(), this = 0xbff350e8
A(a1)::copy-constructor(), this = 0xbff35138
C(c1)::constructor()
A(a1)::destructor(), this = 0xbff350e8
A(a3)::constructor(), this = 0xbff3513c
B(b1)::constructor()
B(b1)::destructor()
A(a3)::destructor(), this = 0xbff3513c
C(c1)::destructor()
A(a1)::destructor(), this = 0xbff35138
A(a2)::destructor(), this = 0xbff35130
A(a1)::destructor(), this = 0xbff3512c
```

[Try it online](http://ideone.com/sjzhGq)

As you can see, one copy-construction happens when you pass a1 as parameter to the constructor of c1 and a second one happens when this constructor initializes its member a. The temporary copy is destructed immediately afterwards while the member is destructed when c is destructed.

**Edit:**
[Here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor) you can read the exact rules when a copy-constructor is created.
In order to not create a default copy-constructor it is not sufficient to provide any user-defined constructor, it needs to be a copy/move-constructor.

**Edit2:**

Taken from C++14 standard (12.8 Copying and moving class objects):

> 7 If the class definition does not explicitly declare a copy constructor, one is declared implicitly. If the class definition declares a move constructor or move assignment operator, the implicitly declared copy constructor is defined as deleted; otherwise, it is defined as defaulted (8.4). The latter case is deprecated if the class has a user-declared copy assignment operator or a user-declared destructor.